# Impact and Implications of drop table in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hash

I had dropped all my tables in one of the Oracle database. And recreated the tables. While I do that, I end up with the following issue, that I found some `hash-valued` `tables` created & resides when I list by `select * from cat;`

```
select * from cat;
....
....
BIN$wNNKvu8PSDetVdeWtGc7mw==$0 TABLE
....
[..]
QRTZ_CALENDARS
....
....
....
....
```

Does it mean anything. Does it implies to anything.

Any advise on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a content of recyclebin.

```
PURGE recyclebin;
```

Or drop your tables with

```
DROP TABLE table_name PURGE;
```

Comment: Does it mean,- is I can retrieve back my tables it by `FLASHBACK TABLE`. If I can is there any bottle-necking constraints. Else it is just ease of use by this query,- `FLASHBACK TABLE`

Comment: You can use FLASHBACK TABLE ... TO BEFORE DROP. Read please documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm for example.

Comment: Oh ok. Does it mean by some default set parameter by which I get this `hash-tables`. I mean default `flashback` is built by in. Else set by

Comment: Sorry, I don't understande what do you mean. You can get list of tables by select * from recyclebin;

Comment: I too don't understand why it is `hashed` and implications of `PURGE` now.... as `DROP TABLE table_name PURGE;` removes hashes too without counterfeiting table removal process. Does the `hash-valued` table has relevance with regards to any process.